# Hyper-V suddenly gets RAW file system

Tags: hyper-v

A few days ago some weird behavior started to appear on some of our Virtual Machines hosted by Hyper-V

At some stage some issues started to occur. Complain 'file or directory not exists' for the files that 100% exist.

When I ran **chksdk** it responded

```
The type of the filesystem is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

But after rebooted the VM chkdsk worked and showed filesystem as NTFS again.

But the issue reoccurred again and again.

I recovered VM from the 100% working backup (a few months old) but the issue persisted.

This cannot be a VM issue because backup is created a few months before the issue occurred first time.

Is that something wrong with the Hyper-V server itself?

Comment: What is the underlying storage system?  Are the VDH files on a locak drive? DAS? SAN?  High availability file server?  And what version of hyperv? Also, side note, why is your backup a few months old?  I'm hoping you just intentionally restored from the oldest available for testing...

Comment: @Grant Hyper-V has RAID 5. VDH on the local drive. Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise - Hyper-V. The VM is a build agent - there is no point to create up-to-date backups

Comment: Run chkdsk on all the host servers drives.

Comment: @Grant I ran chkdsk on the host server drives. It succeeded without any errors. But the issue on VM persist